# chrome native messaging: can a native host executable start with arguments?

Tags: c++, google-chrome, chrome-native-messaging

Is it possible to start the native host with arguments of main(int argc, char** argv)? Writing in background.js is more reasonable, but there is no apis like chrome.runtime.connectNative(string application, string[] arguments). There is only chrome.runtime.connectNative(string application).

Comment: Why don't you put your arguments in the json (pattern to exchange messages by native messaging) and read them from the standard input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to my knowledge the best you can hope to do is create a .bat file (or equivalent) and pass arguments in from there. if you have dynamic data you want to pass from the extension (something you cannot hardcode into a launcher script file), then you will need to develop a protocol to initiate a startup sequence to ensure your parameters have been processed, e.g.

```
   var startupDone = false,
       port = chrome.runtime.connectNative( 'my.native.app' );

   port.onMessage.addListener( function( msg ) { 
      if ( msg.type === 'startupResponse' && msg.done ) startupDone = true;
      else {
         // process normal messages
      }
   } );
   port.postMessage( { type: 'startupRequest', params: [] } );
   ...
   if ( startupDone ) {
      port.postMessage( /* non-startup message */ );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed your executable be jar and it be a third party jar ,then the below may help otherwise rewriting the jar to accept postMessage could be best solution

1. Create a Custom URI and make it to hit a separate bat file
2. Call it from background script
3. Inside the bat create a notepad file and copy your arguments or overwrite your executable bat file with the arguments
4. connectNative to the executable bat which will kick start jar with arguments or take it from the notepad file

Answer (score 0):

If your arguments are dynamic, you can create a small launcher native app that acts like the middle man. It takes in the arguments sent by your Chrome extension and launches the main native app with those arguments. When the main app is launched, the extension can exchange messages with it.

If there's any problem in exchanging messages with the main native app in the scenario above (I've never tried it), you can give more responsibilities to the launcher app and let it relay messages back and forth between the main native app and your extension.